# Composer-rest-server Perform authenticating in the client app automatically

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am creating a web app (angular) which will call hyperledger composer's rest API's. I have used GOOGLE passport setup for authentication.

When I go to http://locahost:3000/explorer from a browser it shows me an access token on top. Using this access token I am able to perform transactions from my APP.

My question is how can I use this without forcing the users to authenticate with composer-rest-server, I mean I would like to know if this is possible to perform authenticating in the client app automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Check the user has a valid business card while login with GOOGLE account. If the result is positive, then allow the user to proceed further in the app otherwise, show a authentication message

Comment: Could you provide some example code to illustrate your proposed solution?

Comment: I don't want to do this scenario, what I want is to skip this rest-server authentication and in same time using multi-user option

Comment: `const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
let businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();

try{
 const definition = await businessNetworkConnection.connect(XXXXXX);
 // Member of business network
}
catch{
 //Not a member of business network
}`

here XXXXXX means CARDNAME. This code does not require any rest-server authentication, simply it checks the card exists or not for the user.